# Base64 decoding issue with Android API

Tags: android, base64, plist

I am trying to decode a string extracted from **“data” tag of plist (Property List) file**.  From official Apple developer website, I understood that

> “data bytes are base-64 encoded between the <data> and </data> tags.”

**Issue:**

**Sample input:**

> 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

**Output generated by online [base64 decoder:](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/base64-encode-decode/)**

> bplist00./T$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiverTroot
>   (U$null
>
> \NSAttributesXNSStringV$class
>   YNS.stringRHiX$classesZ$classname_NSMutableStringXNSStringXNSObject_NSMutableString
>   !”ZNS.objectsWNS.keys$'%&\NSDictionaryXNSObject\NSDictionary)-*+,_NSMutableAttributedString_NSAttributedStringXNSObject_NSMutableAttributedString_NSKeyedArchiver(25:

**Output generated by my code:**

> bplist00./T$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiverTroot

**Here is my code to decode the extracted string:**

```
String result = new String((Base64.decode(extracted_string.getBytes(“UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT)), “UTF-8”));
```

I have tried using different flags of **Base64.decode** function, but none of them were helpful to produce the output same as web tools.

I have following questions:

1. Are there any limitations with **Android base64 API** which are causing the above issue?
2. Are there any alternative Android API which I can use?

I’d appreciate any suggestions on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to check the value of variable result. I think it has the '\n' so console is showing the first line only.

Comment: Thank for the reply but I found same output on console with variable result.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = new String((Base64.decode(extracted_string.getBytes(“UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT)), “UTF-8”));
```

Replace that by:

```
 String result = new String(Base64.decode(extracted_string, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The above code snippet produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by me was correct to decode the base64 encoded string. The Android Studio console was not displaying the entire decoded string (maybe due to limitations with displaying certain characters).